Using Flink and Flink CDC reports an error org.apache.flink.shaded.guava31.com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder
When I used Flink CDC to migrate data to Oracle and SQL Server, the Flink version used was 1.16.0 and the Flink cdc version used was 3.2.0. Then flink-shaded-guava used 31.1-jre-17.0. The error org.apache.flink.shaded.guava30.com.google.common.collect.Lists was reported. But when I used 30.1.1-jre-15.0, the error org.apache.flink.shaded.guava31.com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder was reported. The specific information is as follows:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-shaded-guava</artifactId>
    <version>30.1.1-jre-15.0</version>
</dependency>



Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.shaded.guava31.com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 13 more

When I followed the prompts and used version 31.1-jre-17.0, an error occurred again.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.shaded.guava30.com.google.common.collect.Lists
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 20 more

Switching between versions 30 and 31 still reports an error
